# adding div to right border page with inverted border-radius

Tags: stylesheet, html, css

I am trying to use border-radius property for made the effect which shown by image.
The intention is that one corner, turns in the other direction.

I am using a table with three cells but how you can see, I have to problem with the horitzontal border.
If I remove it and show the other border (of other cell) I have the same problem in the other side.

Any idea of how I can made this?

Thank in advance.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your `table` css:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

it's the best I can think of without seeing any code